# problem when use ViewBinding when use WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewbinding

i use View Binding in android.
crash log :

```
Unable to destroy activity {land.majazi.majaziland/land.majazi.majaziland.views.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.webkit.WebView land.majazi.majaziland.databinding.FrCryptoDetailBinding.webViewChart' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5629)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5674)
android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2309)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8587)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

web View Chart is already exist in XML file , but my app crashing sometimes

**UPDATE**

this is my fragment code (use NavigationComponent in project) :

```java
private FrCryptoDetailBinding binding;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (binding == null) {
        binding = FrCryptoDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        if (getArguments() == null) {
            goBack();
            return null;
        }
        md_cryptoCurrency = getArguments().getParcelable(getOrder());
        binding.setCurrency(md_cryptoCurrency);
        setView(binding.getRoot());
    }
    return binding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    binding.webViewChart.setWebViewClient(null);
    binding = null;
}
```

Comment: You must be accessing the View outside of the lifecycle because usually we nullify binding in `onDestroyView` to avoid memory leaks. add your code with question .

Comment: Show us the code where you access the view and where you inflate the view binding.

Comment: Do not add code as Answer . lets not make it playground . [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71201715/edit) your question instead and add your code with question .

Comment: To answer your question you need to check fragment's state before accessing the Binding object . `if(isAdded())` should work . add this check everywhere when the code is not synchronous .  Alternatively you can remove the listeners when your fragment is destroyed like `WebViewClient` and other .

Comment: @ADM Where do I add this code? `if(isAdded())`